# How can I get the result of a node in my code?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml invoice where the node PeriodWeekNum is. I want to have the Year followed by the Letter W and then the weeknumber --> YYYNWW. Im only getting the year and the letter w --> 2019W. I want to have the result of the node PeriodWeekNum also in my code, but I cant seem to get it.

I already tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice">
      <xsl:if test="x:Header/x:DocumentDateTime"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(x:Header/x:DocumentDateTime,1,4),'W')"/></xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="x:Line/x:UserArea/x:TimeCard/x:ReportedTime/x:PeriodWeekNum"><xsl:value-of select="x:Line/x:UserArea/x:TimeCard/x:ReportedTime/x:PeriodWeekNum"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the xml invoice

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" hrx="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15" nl="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15" schemaLocation="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis ../Invoice.xsd http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15 InvoiceAdditionalNL.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentIds>
<DocumentId>
<Id>19068863</Id>
</DocumentId>
</DocumentIds>
<DocumentDateTime>2019-06-18T00:00:00Z</DocumentDateTime>
<ReasonCode>hours</ReasonCode>
<TotalAmount currency="EUR">58.02</TotalAmount>
<PaymentTerms>
<PaymentTermsDate>2019-06-18T00:00:00Z</PaymentTermsDate>
<NumberOfDays>40</NumberOfDays>
</PaymentTerms>
<Parties>
<BillToParty>
<PartyId>
<Id>012634</Id>
</PartyId>
<Name>BLABLABLA</Name>
<Addresses>
<PrimaryAddress>
<AddressLine>BLABLA 17</AddressLine>
<City>BLABLA</City>
<Country>NL</Country>
<PostalCode>2341 DA</PostalCode>
<Telephone>0123435</Telephone>
</PrimaryAddress>
</Addresses>
<Contacts>
<Contact>
<Description>bladieblad</Description>
</Contact>
</Contacts>
</BillToParty>
<CustomerParty>
<PartyId>
<Id>0123333</Id>
</PartyId>
<Name>Aasdsdasd</Name>
<Addresses>
<PrimaryAddress>
<AddressLine>Nasdasd 44</AddressLine>
<City>REasdsad</City>
<Country>NL</Country>
<PostalCode>1111 AA/PostalCode>
<Telephone>01234344545</Telephone>
</PrimaryAddress>
</Addresses>
<Contacts>
<Contact>
<Description>9008</Description>
</Contact>
</Contacts>
</CustomerParty>
<RemitToParty>
<PartyId>
<Id>8</Id>
</PartyId>
<Name>bladieblad BV</Name>
<TaxId>122323421</TaxId>
<Addresses>
<PrimaryAddress>
<AddressLine>Mercudfsdfsdf 1</AddressLine>
<City>Hsdfsdfds</City>
<PostalCode>1111 DD</PostalCode>
<Description>Hertertertntoor</Description>
<Telephone>12344545-50</Telephone>
</PrimaryAddress>
<SecondaryAddress/>
</Addresses>
<Contacts>
<Contact>
<Description>Addfwefw</Description>
<Addresses>
<PrimaryAddress>
<AddressLine>Pwefwefwe 24</AddressLine>
<City>HEwefwefe</City>
<Country>NL</Country>
<PostalCode>1111 DT</PostalCode>
<Description>Vestiging</Description>
<Telephone>121212</Telephone>
</PrimaryAddress>
<SecondaryAddress>
<AddressLine>Pefefefe</AddressLine>
<City>HEfefe</City>
<Country>NL</Country>
<PostalCode>61212 df</PostalCode>
</SecondaryAddress>
</Addresses>
</Contact>
</Contacts>
</RemitToParty>
<SupplierParty>
<PartyId>
<Id>8</Id>
</PartyId>
<Name>Oereere3r</Name>
<TaxId>ererere44B01</TaxId>
<Addresses>
<PrimaryAddress>
<AddressLine>Mefefegfefe 1</AddressLine>
<City>HOefefefe</City>
<PostalCode>2111 HA</PostalCode>
<Description>H3r344343</Description>
<Telephone>0122212120</Telephone>
</PrimaryAddress>
<SecondaryAddress/>
</Addresses>
<Contacts>
<Contact>
<Description>blabla</Description>
<Addresses>
<PrimaryAddress>
<AddressLine>ererer 24</AddressLine>
<City>HererN</City>
<Country>NL</Country>
<PostalCode>6111 LT</PostalCode>
<Description>Ve34343stg</Description>
<Telephone>026 47errer5</Telephone>
</PrimaryAddress>
<SecondaryAddress>
<AddressLine>Pooererer 24</AddressLine>
<City>Hererere</City>
<Country>NL</Country>
<PostalCode>6611 dd</PostalCode>
</SecondaryAddress>
</Addresses>
</Contact>
</Contacts>
</SupplierParty>
</Parties>
<Type>Both</Type>
<Reason>regular</Reason>
<TotalCharges currency="EUR">47.95</TotalCharges>
<TotalTax currency="EUR">10.07</TotalTax>
<Tax>
<TaxAmount currency="EUR">10.07</TaxAmount>
<TaxBaseAmount currency="EUR">47.95</TaxBaseAmount>
<PercentQuantity uom="BTW">21.00</PercentQuantity>
</Tax>
<UserArea>
<StaffingAdditionalData xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderNumber/>
<CostCenterCode>9523</CostCenterCode>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
<ReferenceInformation>
<StaffingSupplierId idOwner="StaffingCustomer">
<IdValue>8</IdValue>
</StaffingSupplierId>
<StaffingCustomerId idOwner="StaffingCustomer">
<IdValue>012634</IdValue>
</StaffingCustomerId>
<StaffingCustomerOrgUnitId idOwner="StaffingCustomer">
<IdValue name="Ablabla"/>
</StaffingCustomerOrgUnitId>
</ReferenceInformation>
</StaffingAdditionalData>
<StaffingOrganization typeOfOrganization="Supplier" xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<Organization>
<OrganizationName>Oldedede</OrganizationName>
</Organization>
<PaymentInfo>
<BankAccountInfo>
<BankInfoByJurisdiction bankJurisdiction="NL">
<BankCode>BANKBANK</BankCode>
<BankWindow/>
<BankAccountNumber>NLBDEUBDUEBDEUBD</BankAccountNumber>
<BankAccountKey/>
<BankAccountType>IBAN</BankAccountType>
</BankInfoByJurisdiction>
<BankAccountForeign/>
</BankAccountInfo>
</PaymentInfo>
</StaffingOrganization>
<StaffingOrganizationNL xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<ChamberofCommerceReference>27ededed</ChamberofCommerceReference>
</StaffingOrganizationNL>
</UserArea>
</Header>
<Line>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<ReasonCode/>
<Charges>
<TotalCharge>
<Total currency="EUR">-815.60</Total>
</TotalCharge>
</Charges>
<DocumentReferences>
<InvoiceDocumentReference>
<DocumentIds>
<DocumentId>
<Id>1edede</Id>
</DocumentId>
</DocumentIds>
</InvoiceDocumentReference>
</DocumentReferences>
<Line>
<LineNumber>1A</LineNumber>
<Charges>
<TotalCharge>
<Total currency="EUR">-775.60</Total>
</TotalCharge>
</Charges>
<Tax>
<PercentQuantity uom="BTW">21.00</PercentQuantity>
</Tax>
<Price>
<Amount currency="EUR">22.16</Amount>
<PerQuantity uom="regular">1</PerQuantity>
</Price>
<ItemQuantity uom="regular">-35.00</ItemQuantity>
</Line>
<Line>
<LineNumber>1B</LineNumber>
<Charges>
<TotalCharge>
<Total currency="EUR">-40.00</Total>
</TotalCharge>
</Charges>
<Tax>
<PercentQuantity uom="BTW">21.00</PercentQuantity>
</Tax>
<Price>
<Amount currency="EUR">8.00</Amount>
<PerQuantity uom="Travel expenses">1</PerQuantity>
</Price>
<ItemQuantity uom="Travel expenses">-5.00</ItemQuantity>
</Line>
<UserArea>
<TimeCard xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<Id idOwner="StaffingCustomer">
<IdValue>Aedede</IdValue>
</Id>
<ReportedResource>
<Person>
<Id idOwner="StaffingCustomer">
<IdValue>151MIET001</IdValue>
</Id>
<PersonName>
<FormattedName>M. edededed</FormattedName>
<LegalName>M. Mdededede</LegalName>
<GivenName>Maededed</GivenName>
<PreferredGivenName>Mdedede</PreferredGivenName>
<FamilyName>Miededed</FamilyName>
</PersonName>
</Person>
</ReportedResource>
<ReportedTime>
<PeriodStartDate>2019-05-20T00:00:00Z</PeriodStartDate>
<PeriodEndDate>2019-05-26T00:00:00Z</PeriodEndDate>
<PeriodWeekNum>21</PeriodWeekNum>
<TimeInterval type="regular" billable="true">
<StartDateTime>2019-05-20T00:00:00Z</StartDateTime>
<EndDateTime>2019-05-26T00:00:00Z</EndDateTime>
<Duration>35.00</Duration>
<RateOrAmount currency="EUR" type="Hourly" multiplier="100.00">22.16</RateOrAmount>
<AdditionalData>
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderLineItem>0</PurchaseOrderLineItem>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
</AdditionalData>
</TimeInterval>
<Allowance type="Travel expenses" billable="true">
<Id>
<IdValue name="allowance"/>
</Id>
<StartDate>2019-05-20T00:00:00Z</StartDate>
<EndDate>2019-05-26T00:00:00Z</EndDate>
<Amount currency="EUR">8.00</Amount>
<Quantity>5.00</Quantity>
<AdditionalData>
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderLineItem>0</PurchaseOrderLineItem>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
</AdditionalData>
</Allowance>
</ReportedTime>
<SubmitterInfo>
<SubmittedDateTime>2019-06-19</SubmittedDateTime>
</SubmitterInfo>
<AdditionalData>
<StaffingAdditionalData xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderNumber/>
<CostCenterCode>9523</CostCenterCode>
<ProjectCode/>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
<ReferenceInformation>
<AssignmentId idOwner="StaffingCompany">
<IdValue>1510009388</IdValue>
</AssignmentId>
</ReferenceInformation>
</StaffingAdditionalData>
</AdditionalData>
</TimeCard>
<StaffingAdditionalData xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderNumber/>
<CostCenterCode>9523</CostCenterCode>
<ProjectCode/>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
</StaffingAdditionalData>
</UserArea>
</Line>
<Line>
<LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
<ReasonCode/>
<Charges>
<TotalCharge>
<Total currency="EUR">863.55</Total>
</TotalCharge>
</Charges>
<Line>
<LineNumber>2A</LineNumber>
<Charges>
<TotalCharge>
<Total currency="EUR">823.55</Total>
</TotalCharge>
</Charges>
<Tax>
<PercentQuantity uom="BTW">21.00</PercentQuantity>
</Tax>
<Price>
<Amount currency="EUR">23.53</Amount>
<PerQuantity uom="regular">1</PerQuantity>
</Price>
<ItemQuantity uom="regular">35.00</ItemQuantity>
</Line>
<Line>
<LineNumber>2B</LineNumber>
<Charges>
<TotalCharge>
<Total currency="EUR">40.00</Total>
</TotalCharge>
</Charges>
<Tax>
<PercentQuantity uom="BTW">21.00</PercentQuantity>
</Tax>
<Price>
<Amount currency="EUR">8.00</Amount>
<PerQuantity uom="Travel expenses">1</PerQuantity>
</Price>
<ItemQuantity uom="Travel expenses">5.00</ItemQuantity>
</Line>
<UserArea>
<TimeCard xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<Id idOwner="StaffingCustomer">
<IdValue/>
</Id>
<ReportedResource>
<Person>
<Id idOwner="StaffingCustomer">
<IdValue>15ededed</IdValue>
</Id>
<PersonName>
<FormattedName>Mdededed</FormattedName>
<LegalName>M. Mideded</LegalName>
<GivenName>Mdededede</GivenName>
<PreferredGivenName>Mdedede</PreferredGivenName>
<FamilyName>Mideedede</FamilyName>
</PersonName>
</Person>
</ReportedResource>
<ReportedTime>
<PeriodStartDate>2019-05-20T00:00:00Z</PeriodStartDate>
<PeriodEndDate>2019-05-26T00:00:00Z</PeriodEndDate>
<PeriodWeekNum>21</PeriodWeekNum>
<TimeInterval type="regular" billable="true">
<StartDateTime>2019-05-20T00:00:00Z</StartDateTime>
<EndDateTime>2019-05-26T00:00:00Z</EndDateTime>
<Duration>35.00</Duration>
<RateOrAmount currency="EUR" type="Hourly" multiplier="100.00">23.53</RateOrAmount>
<AdditionalData>
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderLineItem>0</PurchaseOrderLineItem>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
</AdditionalData>
</TimeInterval>
<Allowance type="Travel expenses" billable="true">
<Id>
<IdValue name="allowance"/>
</Id>
<StartDate>2019-05-20T00:00:00Z</StartDate>
<EndDate>2019-05-26T00:00:00Z</EndDate>
<Amount currency="EUR">8.00</Amount>
<Quantity>5.00</Quantity>
<AdditionalData>
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderLineItem>0</PurchaseOrderLineItem>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
</AdditionalData>
</Allowance>
</ReportedTime>
<SubmitterInfo>
<SubmittedDateTime>2019-06-19</SubmittedDateTime>
</SubmitterInfo>
<AdditionalData>
<StaffingAdditionalData xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderNumber/>
<CostCenterCode>9523</CostCenterCode>
<ProjectCode/>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
<ReferenceInformation>
<AssignmentId idOwner="StaffingCompany">
<IdValue>1510009552</IdValue>
</AssignmentId>
</ReferenceInformation>
</StaffingAdditionalData>
</AdditionalData>
</TimeCard>
<StaffingAdditionalData xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
<CustomerReportingRequirements>
<PurchaseOrderNumber/>
<CostCenterCode>9523</CostCenterCode>
<ProjectCode/>
</CustomerReportingRequirements>
</StaffingAdditionalData>
</UserArea>
</Line>
</Invoice>
```

I know the XML is poorly written, but this is the xml we getting.. I need to do it with this.

Expected result should be 2019W21 but the actual result is now 2019W. Can someone help me with what Im doing wrong?

PS: I deleted confidential information, thats why you see BLADIABLAD etc.

Comment: Can someone please help me??

Comment: `PeriodWeekNum` appears twice in your XML. In this case, they both have the same value (21), but could the values ever be different. If so, what would be the expected result?

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you for your feedback. The values could be different. I need to have the highest value selected in my result. So for example if I have week 22 and 23, my result should be 2019W23.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have is that `Timecard` and all it descendants, and in a different namespace to `Invoice`

```
 <TimeCard xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
```

So, you need to declare that namespace in your XSLT (any prefix will do here. It is the URI that must match)

```
xmlns:t="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15"
```

Then your xpath expression becomes like so:

```
x:Line/x:UserArea/t:TimeCard/t:ReportedTime/t:PeriodWeekNum
```

In terms of getting the maximum week number, you need to replace the `xsl:if` with an `xsl:for-each` which can then be sorted in descending order.

```
<xsl:for-each select="x:Line/x:UserArea/t:TimeCard/t:ReportedTime/t:PeriodWeekNum">
  <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" />
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Try this complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis"
    xmlns:t="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice">
      <xsl:if test="x:Header/x:DocumentDateTime"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(x:Header/x:DocumentDateTime,1,4),'W')"/></xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each select="x:Line/x:UserArea/t:TimeCard/t:ReportedTime/t:PeriodWeekNum">
         <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" />
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I've tried your complete XSLT in my software, but It doesnt seem to recognize it. It says that the code is invalid. Im not an expert on this one. is it possible to add the text "2019W" hard, before the weeknumber node? That way I don't get results from 2 different nodes, but from 1 (PeriodWeekNum) but with the text 2019W before the node? I mean that if there is an XSLT option/formule to try getting the text before the result of the node?

Comment: Do note your XML is invalid, as you have a `<PostalCode>1111 AA/PostalCode>` element in it, so it is not well-formed. But if you fix that, you can see it in action at  http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWP

Comment: Hi tim, in the original XML the postal code is wel written. I took some information out of it because its confidential. This is the XML I receive. So the xml is coming from the supplier, I cant change how the XML is. I only can map information I have to get the result I want.. But im really struggling with this..

Comment: The XSLT in the answer does give the required result (See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWP). If you put your real XML in that website (no need to save it, so no-one else will be able to see it), do you get the expected result?

Comment: It does give the required result on that site (with the original XML). However, I can't copy paste ur path because it says the mapping for the xslt is invalid. Its not your code but my software.. I removed the spaces between some lines and formulas, but getting the same error message.